# Cannot import Objective C++ wrapper class into my Swift code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, objective-c++

I have an Objective C++ wrapper class called *ImageDividerWrapper* in which there is a function I want to use in a Swift class called *FrameProcessor*.

Inside the *ImageDividerWrapper.h* file I made sure to import the bridging header. I also double-checked that the bridging header was referenced and spelled correctly in Project/Build Settings/Swift Compiler. I also deleted derived data, cleaned build folder, etc..

Also imported ImageDividerWrapper.h into my bridging header file:

```
#import "ImageDividerWrapper.h"
```

And in my ImageDividerWrapper header file I include:

```
#import "Vsn3-Bridging-Header.h"
```

Unfortunately, I still continue to get the error: "No such module 'ImageDividerWrapper'" when trying to directly import the Objective C++ class into my Swift file with:

```
import ImageDividerWrapper
```

If anyone who has solved this problem before can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it so much!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the second import line is unnecessary. You need to just:

1. Import the header file: `#import "ImageDividerWrapper.h"`
2. Then just use the class! (e.g. `let thisDivider = ImageDividerWrapper()`)

Comment: Previously commented that this didn't work. Turns out I was wrongly referencing the Objective C++ class. Its file name is ImageDividerWrapper but the class is actually named ImageProcessorWrapper. I feel like a doofus, but for any future readers out there don't be alarmed. Just make damn sure everything is referenced correctly. Thank you Ben!